# Converter data 20171130 para formato 30/11/2017 em string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados

Estou com esse campo de data '20171130' salvo no banco, e preciso converter para formatação em string "30/11/2017", na minha aplicação, **como fazer esse tipo de conversão ?**.

Comment: Em que momento você quer fazer essa conversão, jovem? No banco ou na aplicação?

Comment: Boa, irei editar para especificar melhor. @LINQ

Comment: porque voce nao salva no banco assim "30/11/2017"?

Comment: Por que recebo um json nesse formato e ja salva direto no banco. @JulioHenrique97

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível usar [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) para converter a *string* numa instância de `DateTime` e depois fazer qualquer formatação.

```
var strDate = "20171130"; // Este é o valor recuperado do banco
DateTime dateValue;
DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue);     

Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

<sup>[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KmLl2Q)</sup>

Comment: Retira o new do CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, pois é statico... da forma como está não funciona...

Comment: @samuelrvg tinha ficado do código antigo. Obg

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa converter.
Se estiver pegando os dados de um banco de dados, já pega convertido pelo select.
Exemplo:

```
SELECT *,date_format(`data`,'%d/%m/%Y') as `data_formatada` FROM tabela
```

Assim ele pega todos os dados da tabela e, a data nova, vai ficar com o nome de data_formatada.

Comment: Blz, mas nesse caso como ficaria o select ? utilizo Entity Framework

Comment: Acho que o sql é igual em todas as linguagens, porque você vai manipular direto o banco de dados. Então basta adaptar esta query ao teu código C#.